# How to get Person or Group user details from REST API query

Tags: 2013, rest, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, query

I am having trouble trying to get the "Title" portion of a Person or Group field from SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow using a REST API query. I have my workflow built similar to the one in this article: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013

My url variable is grabbing all the items in a list with a Status equal to 'Not Started'. I have a Person or Group column in the List called 'Assigned To'. However when just trying to use a Get action to get the person's name, it returns their user ID, as seen below:

Get **AssignedTo** from **Variable: item** (Output to **Variable: assignedTo**)

I have tried AssignedTo/Title to no avail.

Should I expand my url (REST query) to expand the Assigned To field: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo/Id

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! It was all about expanding my REST query with adding AssignedTo/Title to the $select portion.